# firebaseinstanceid.getinstance().gettoken() возвращает null

Tags: java, firebase

Здравствуйте!

Начал работать с firebase уведомлениями и неожиданно возникла проблема.

На одном из устройств с андройд 4.2.2 функция `firebaseinstanceid.getinstance().gettoken()` возвращает `null`.

На устройствах с андройд 5+ всё хорошо.

**Вопрос:** может быть что-то сталкивался с подобным? В чем может быть причина?